# How to access child class entity fields in native query?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, native-sql

i have two entity classes both are in relation.am skipping annoatation part and remaining fields in the below code.

```
class Employee{
  Department department;
}
class Department{
 String departmentName;
}
```

when i try to access departmentName in native sql query am getting error unknown column. 
query is
select * from employee where employee.department.departmentname=?; 
how can i access child class entities? some one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Native query as the name suggest is pure SQL dialect of the underlying db server and has nothing to do with HQL/JPQL. You have to use JOIN with actual tables and column names.

Comment: I have a little knowledge of queries. I have made them in a relation using annotation. Now i want to fetch employee objects based on the department name. Can you please tell me how that query actually looks like

Comment: From your question, it's hard to know what you are doing. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question.